# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a wireframe in matplot lib and I had the original problem of the wireframe not looking like a mesh. I found the answer of useing numpy.meshgrid(). I proceeded to use this solution but when I try to show the graph I get the error

line 1727, in plot_wireframe
    rows, cols = Z.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
file=open(ob,'r')
points=ast.literal_eval(file.read())
file.close()

fig=plt.figure()
ax=mplot3d.Axes3D(fig)

newpoints=point_sep(points)
x=newpoints[0]
y=newpoints[1]
z=newpoints[2]

mgrid=np.meshgrid(x,y,z,sparse=True)

x1=mgrid[0]
y1=mgrid[1]
z1=mgrid[2][0]


ax.plot_wireframe(x1,y1,z1)

ax.set_xlim3d(-1*(wall_depth*15),wall_depth*15)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
```

In this code i am retrieving the coordinates from a file

Comment: Some sample data would be quite helpful.

Comment: I don't see `cols = Z.shape` in your code block. However, this error means that a function call is returning 2 values but you are only unpacking one. Try `cols, some_other_var = Z.shape`

Comment: You're not using `meshgrid` correctly. Try with `x1, y1 = meshgrid(x, y)`. Wireframe assumes `x` and `y` give the coordinates and `z` the values, so they are all 2D, but the way you're using meshgrid is to make a 3D mesh (so x, y, and z are all 3D and not 2D). (In general, when you have errors about the shapes, it's helpful to print out the shapes and see what they are. Unless I'm working only in 1D or have done the thing many times, I almost never write numpy code where I don't print out shapes as I go along.)

Comment: Also, if you made an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you would already have an answer and not just a collection of pointers and tips. The lack of answers here is not because nobody's interested but because you haven't given enough information for us to meaningfully help.